# Swap the default x y coordinate system of Opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I know that the default coordinate system of Opencv is as follows:
[image]

My question is 
Is there a way (opencv's function) to swap the default x and y axes such that the x axis is the vertical line and the y axis is the horizon line. So I can calculate the geometric transformation matrices based on this new coordinate system?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? However, [transposing](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transpose) or [flipping](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip) your matrix should produce the desired effect.

Comment: Hi, @Miki In fact, I want to use the matrix obtained by cv2.getAffineTransform in another piece of software, this software assumes the x axis is the vertical line.
The matrix returned by cv2.getAffineTransform is a 2*3 matrix, how can I change this matrix to meet the software’s requirements? Thanks

Comment: OpenCV is based on numpy system (in python). If you want to change a pixel in your image (and you are using python) simply swap the indices. I.e changing the red of a pixel in x,y position issomething like `image[y,x,3] = newvalue` (remember that openCv) also has BGR structure